# SQL Server : Merge and Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to simplify some domain logic, rather then separate queries was attempting to utilize a merge to load a single query file as a resource within my application.  But I appear to run into the:

> The merge statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint

I'll create a smaller example to demonstrate my issue:

Table One: "Customer"

- Id
- Other columns...

Table Two: "Rates"

- Id
- CustomerId   <-- foreign key
- Other columns...

In theory, if a customer is created it should leverage the id created for the second merge in rates.  If an update for customer occurs, then the id would then be used for the second merge or simply used passed parameter from code.

```
DECLARE @Identifier INT;
DECLARE @CustomerAudit TABLE (
          Action NVARCHAR(MAX)
     ,    Id INT
);

MERGE INTO [web].[Customers] AS destination
USING (VALUES (@Id, @OtherColumns)) AS source (Id, OtherColumns)
      ON (@Id = destination.[Id])

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
        INSERT (OtherColumns) VALUES (@OtherColumns)

WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN 
        UPDATE 
        SET destination.[OtherColumns] = @OtherColumns

OUTPUT $action, inserted.[Id] INTO @CustomerAudit


SELECT @Identifier = [Id] 
FROM @CustomerAudit 
WHERE @Identifier = Id

MERGE INTO [web].[Rates] AS destination
USING (VALUES (@Id, @Customer, @OtherColumns)) AS source (Id)
      ON (@Id = destination.[Id] AND COALESCE(@Identifier, @Customer) = destination.[Customer])

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
        INSERT (Customer, OtherColumns) 
        VALUES (COALESCE(@Identifier, @Customer), @OtherColumns)

WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN 
        UPDATE SET destination.[OtherColumns] = @OtherColumns

OUTPUT $action, inserted.*;
DELETE FROM @CustomerAudit;
```

The other columns have been truncated for brevity, but should convey intent.  The focus should be on the index constraints.  If I query the `@CustomerAudit` (not as a declared table but a full table) I can clearly see the inserted record with a match to the source.  But the second merge appears to have a key constraint issue.  Though I see the key in the table.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that:

```
SELECT @Identifier = [Id] 
FROM @CustomerAudit 
WHERE @Identifier = Id
```

should be

```
SELECT @Identifier = [Id] 
FROM @CustomerAudit 
WHERE Id = @Id;
```

Or simply resgining from @Identfier variable and using @Id instead.

Comment: Wouldn't the @Id be a zero from the application though for an insert, so the output record would not be found with Id?

Comment: @Greg The condition `WHERE @Identifier = Id` will compare NULL against column Id which is always not true(unknown actually). So the @Identifier is always NULL in that case.

Comment: I did not know that,  but it does make sense.